# React Need help Syncfusion data grid

Tags: reactjs, forms, datagrid, grid

Iam new to react and I am trying to make the following.

I want to create a simple username and password form,
then add the data from username and password form and display it in a grid in the same page. Then update the grid every time I add a user (user name and password).

So here is my form where i get the user name only :

```
        <div >
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <label htmlFor="username">Enter username</label>
                  <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
                  <button>Send data!</button>
              </form>
            </div>
```

I want to know how to do this exactly ? 
Do i have to create a son file then map it and display it in a grid? 
Or can i just save it in the state variable , then display every update ? 
Or there is another solution for that?

Edit:  Following is my code,

```
    import React from "react";
    import {GridComponent, ColumnsDirective, Page , Inject} from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids';
    import productsApi from './getJson'
    import ddata from '../pages/source.json'


      export default class products extends React.Component  {
        constructor() {

          super();
          this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
          this.state =
                  {
                    QrCode : '',
                    newProducts : []
                  }

              }



              // this one is not working at all
        componentDidMount(){   
          productsApi.getAll().then( data => { 
            this.setState({
              newProducts : data

            } )   
           },
           )


        }

        handleSubmit(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          this.setState({
            QrCode: event.target.elements.username.value}
            );
        }


        render() {

          return (
          <div >

            <div >
                  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                      <label htmlFor="username">Enter username</label>
                      <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
                      <button>Send data!</button>
                  </form>
                </div>  



                <div style={{margin: '10%', marginTop : '5%'}}>

                <GridComponent dataSource={ddata}  allowPaging={true} pageSettings= {{pageSize:100}}>

                    <Inject  services ={[Page]}/>
                </GridComponent>
                </div>  

            </div>

          );
        }
      }
```

Here is my sample json,

```
[
    {
        "id":0,
        "Qr":1234567891,
        "Stat":"A",
        "name":"Hello world"

    },
    {
        "id":0,
        "Qr":1234567891,
        "Stat":"A",
        "name":"Hello world"

    },
    {
        "id":0,
        "Qr":1234567891,
        "Stat":"A",
        "name":"Hello world"

    },
    {
        "id":0,
        "Qr":1234567891,
        "Stat":"A",
        "name":"Hello world"

    },
    {
        "id":0,
        "Qr":1234567891,
        "Stat":"A",
        "name":"Hello world"

    },
    {
        "id":0,
        "Qr":1234567891,
        "Stat":"A",
        "name":"Hello world"

    }

]
```

I hope you can help me solve that problem .
Thank you

Comment: It's depend on type of data you're working on. If you have a DB where your info is saved then you will need to trigger something like rest API and bind the content of db using another api. Or if you're not storing it anywhere use state or state container like redux. You can use a combination of above method too.

Comment: i'am acctuelly saving it into the state , but the grid wont show up for some reason .

Comment: Can you show your attempted code or code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working sample created on Code Sandbox,

Important things are,

- Your class name should be Uppercase like `Product`.
- Since you haven't published the `getJson` file, I created a one with the given function which basically loads the data from already resolved. Don't duplicate same data with a variable.
- Then since you're using *SyncFusion* Grid, there is created event, don't use `ComponentDidMount` to bind the grid initially, use created event.
- Grid doesn't automatically refreshed in this instance, you need to use *SyncFusion* way of doing it. That's by getting a ref and use it to access the instance and call refresh.
- You can use controlled input for your text boxes instead of using event argument in `onSubmit` event.
- When in `onSubmit`, you get the already bound items, push your new item with the information from textbox. Then update the state and update the ui.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  GridComponent,
  ColumnsDirective,
  Page,
  Inject
} from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids";
import productsApi from "./getJson";

export default class Products extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.userNameChanged = this.userNameChanged.bind(this);
    this.created = this.created.bind(this);
    this.grid = null;
    this.state = {
      QrCode: "",
      newProducts: [],
      userName: ""
    };
  }


  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let products = this.state.newProducts;
    products.push({
      id: 0,
      Qr: 1234567891,
      Stat: "A",
      name: this.state.userName
    });
    this.setState({
      newProducts: products
    });
    this.grid.refresh();
  }

  userNameChanged(evt) {
    this.setState({
      userName: evt.target.value
    });
  }

  created(){
    productsApi.getAll().then(data => {
      console.log("x", data);
      this.setState({
        newProducts: data
      });

      this.grid.refresh();
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.newProducts);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="username">Enter username</label>
            <input
              onChange={this.userNameChanged}
              value={this.state.userName}
              id="username"
              name="username"
              type="text"
            />
            <button>Send data!</button>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div style={{ margin: "10%", marginTop: "5%" }}>
          <GridComponent
            ref={g => (this.grid = g)}
            dataSource={this.state.newProducts}
            created={this.created}
            allowPaging={true}
            pageSettings={{ pageSize: 100 }}
          >
            <Inject services={[Page]} />
          </GridComponent>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

getJson file,

```
const productsApi = {
  getAll: function() {
    //some ajax request
    return Promise.resolve([
      {
        id: 0,
        Qr: 1234567891,
        Stat: "A",
        name: "Hello world"
      },
      {
        id: 0,
        Qr: 1234567891,
        Stat: "A",
        name: "Hello world"
      },
      {
        id: 0,
        Qr: 1234567891,
        Stat: "A",
        name: "Hello world"
      },
      {
        id: 0,
        Qr: 1234567891,
        Stat: "A",
        name: "Hello world"
      },
      {
        id: 0,
        Qr: 1234567891,
        Stat: "A",
        name: "Hello world"
      },
      {
        id: 0,
        Qr: 1234567891,
        Stat: "A",
        name: "Hello world"
      }
    ]);
  }
};

export default productsApi;
```

Updated codesandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-euclid-o7ire

Comment: Also, try to update your question with the code by clicking on the edit link below your question, so the others can understand who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example where I used `material ui` for input field and table.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default function FormExample() {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
    const [row, setRow] = useState({
        username: '',
        password: ''
    });

    function changeHandler(event) {
        setRow({...row, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <TextField id="username" name="username" label="Username" onChange={changeHandler}/>
                <TextField id="password" name="password" label="Password" onChange={changeHandler}/>
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => {
                    let data = [...rows];
                    data.push(row);
                    setRows(data);
                }}>
                    Save
                </Button>
            </form>

            <h3>User List</h3>
            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                <Table aria-label="simple table">
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>Username</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Password</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {rows.map((row) => (
                            <TableRow key={row.name}>
                                <TableCell>{row.username}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{row.password}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        ))}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </div>
    );
}
```